# adverb emphasis

Tags: adverbial-phrases

> Mother either cooks something special for us or takes us to a restaurant at weekends.

What does "at the weekends" emphasize?
Cooks something special for us or takes us to a restaurant?

Comment: Neither. It is telling us when. And it should be "*on* weekends".

Answer (score 1):

User3169 is right, it is ***on weekends***. It is unclear in the sentence whether ***on weekends*** modifies the entire sentence or just the second part (***takes us to a restaurant***), but if I had to guess, I would guess the entire sentence.

If you want to emphasize that on every weekend, mother either cooks something special or takes us out to a restaurant, then you can accomplish that by starting the sentence with ***on weekends***.

> *On weekends, mother either cooks something special or takes us out to a restaurant.*

If you would like to emphasize that mother cooks during the week, but on the weekend she takes us out to eat, you can accomplish that by saying:

> *Mother either cooks something special or on weekends takes us out to a restaurant.*

By putting the modifying phrase directly in front of the clause, you are making it clear to the reader which clause the phrase is describing.